# api 2.0 file upload response

Tags: box-api

The api 2.0 documentation says that upon a successful file upload, a full file object is returned, but the following is the json I get back on file uploads in Postman and python3:

```
{
    "total_count":1,
    "entries":[
        {
            "type":"file",
            "id":"2244718677",
            "name":"api.py",
            "shared":"0",
            "parent_folder":
                {
                "id":"0"
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. The returned object should be a full file object. We are working on fixing this currently. I'll update my response here once it's been resolved.

Comment: Hi, I just tried yesterday, still showing a short response only. Any idea when it is fixed?

Comment: We're rolling out a fix this evening that you should see immediately…let us know if you don't see the change tomorrow.

Comment: The server returned 404 not found... it was working before this, with shorter return information.